# Nested tables with tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have nested tables within a table that has the tablesorter applied to it.

It adds sort headers to the nested tables, but they don't sort the rows and a Javascript error is thrown.

[image]

I would like to have either:

- the nested tables not sortable
- the sorting on the nest tables actually work.

but not the status quo.

Answer (score 7):

Your first option is much easier (making the nested tables not sortable):

Construct the table something like so:

`$('.tablesorter').tablesorter({selectorHeaders: '> thead > tr > th'});`

And then you might also need to prefix all your css with something like:

`table.tablesorter > thead > tr > ...`