# Nested jQuery Tablesorter tables, all sortable

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to get the jQuery [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin to work with nested tables, where both the inner and outer tables are sortable. Each row of the outer table normally contains a button that, when clicked, reveals a hidden inner table in the row just below it (although I've skipped the button in the HTML below for simplicity, making everything initially visible).

The inner table is in a row with a class of "expand-child", which tells Tablesorter to keep it with the row just above it when sorted. This mostly works, but the outer table headers aren't highlighting correctly when clicked, and the inner table isn't sorting right at all.

I know about [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252733/nested-tables-with-tablesorter), and that one solution is to disable sorting on the inner table, but I specifically want both the outer and inner tables to be sortable.

My HTML is below, and I've also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vad5w/) displaying the problem. Thanks for any help.

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Honda</td>
            <td>Accord</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expand-child">
            <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0 30px 0 30px;">
                <table class="tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Doors</th>
                            <th>Colors</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Honda 2-Door</td>
                            <td>Honda Red</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Honda 4-Door</td>
                            <td>Honda Blue</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Toyota</td>
            <td>Camry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expand-child">
            <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0 30px 0 30px;">
                <table class="tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Doors</th>
                            <th>Colors</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Toyota 2-Door</td>
                            <td>Toyota Yellow</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Toyota 4-Door</td>
                            <td>Toyota Green</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have forked your jsfiddle and updated with selectors so as it orders as I think you want it... http://jsfiddle.net/P2DsY/

You can see from my fork that you just needed to be specific with the table sorter plugin configuration.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! After playing with your jsfiddle a bit, I see that the only change really needed is adding the tablesorter parameter {selectorHeaders: '> thead > tr > th'}. The default is 'thead th', which I realize now causes a problem because the outer table ends up selecting elements all the way down into the inner tables as well. The > signs make it only look at its direct children, not all descendants. I wonder if yours should be the tablesorter default instead. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: I ran into another problem with this later when I tried to disable the sorting on the first column header. If you add "headers: { 0: { sorter: false } }", it disables the first column of all tables, even the nested ones. To disable them individually, instead add inline meta data to the <th> element: class="{sorter: false}" (and include jquery.metadata.js, as the tablesorter docs say to do).

Comment: Did something change?  When I click on the table headers in your fiddle it does not maintain the parent child relationship.

Comment: @JeffBorden: That jsFiddle is using my fork of tablesorter and I have since renamed the default child row from `expand-child` to `tablesorter-childRow`. I've update the [above demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/P2DsY/84/). And as @RusselG mentioned, I have since made the default `selectorHeaders` into `'> thead th, > thead td'`

Comment: @RussellG The reason the nested tables also get their first column disabled is because the initialization function `$('table')` targets all three tables - [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/P2DsY/85/). And since you're using my fork of tablesorter (I think), you can just use `sorter-false` as a class name in the header cell instead of `{sorter:false}`; I'm trying to move away from using the metadata plugin.