# How to divide a table into multiple groups each has its own header which is used to sort its group using jQuery-tablesorter plugin ??

Tags: tablesorter

[Take a look at this demo](http://sdc.com.jo/english/index.php?report_type=2&security_type=1&year=2011&option=com_public&Itemid=28)

How  tablesorter could help me to do such table ??

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449950/nested-jquery-tablesorter-tables-all-sortable) will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, tablesorter can't handle independent sorts within a single table.

The best you can manage is separate, abutting tables, each with `.tablesorter()` invoked on it.